# How to get part of a jena OntModel？

Tags: sparql, jena, ontology

I‘m working on a project, which the ontology is very large and can not be separated into multi files. I need to analyse the ontology and show part of  on a web page, but I am not sure how to get part of the ontology. I've saved the ontology into a OntModel class,should I use jena API or SPARQL to query part of it? It would be the best if the sub ontology is also can convert to OntModel class. Could you please give me an example please? Please help me，any answer would be appreciated！Thank you！

Comment: There's not enough information to answer your question yet.  What do you mean by "part of a model"?  What is it that you would want to show on the web page?  It's not hard to pull out "part of a model" with a SPARQL construct query, but we'll need more information about what you're trying to get out of it…

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, Joshua Taylor. part of model means,I want to get part of a ontology(eg just 3 classes). I know that "part of a model" with a SPARQL construct query is not hard,but the result is like `Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryStr);
  //query.serialize(new IndentedWriter(System.out, true));

  QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
  ResultSet rs = qexec.execSelect();
  while (rs.hasNext()) {
   QuerySolution qs = rs.nextSolution();}`but I want convert ResultSet or QuerySolution to an OntoModel type. Thank you again

Comment: The result of a SPARQL construct query _is_ a model, so you could actually just execute the constructor query (or maybe a `describe` query would work for you, depending on what you mean by "part of a model", you still haven't provided details), and then you can just create an OntModel with that result model as its base model.  If you can provide more details about what you want as "part of a model", we can probably make this work.